# Execution speed problems on Edge and Safari

Tags: selenium-webdriver, safari, microsoft-edge, browser-automation

I have a suite of WebDriver tests that run perfectly in Chrome, Firefox and IE.  When I try the same code on Edge or Safari, I encounter an identical problem: the tests run too fast and try to click things before the page fully loads. I've played with WebDriverWait, ExplicitWait, etc. to no avail.

When I put sleeps in various locations, the tests slow down enough so they work, but obviously I don't want to do that.  Anyone know of a simple way to slow down test execution - or if there is a common problem with these 2 browsers?  Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to use `WebDriverWait` to wait for the slowest browsers but not slow down the fast browsers. Post one of the scenarios where you need the script to wait, the HTML, and the code you have tried and we'll help you get it working.

Comment: I observe the same behavior with Edge - tests that are working perfectly with Chrome, Firefox, IE - are flaky on Edge. I've also already implemented proper waits on FindElement/s() so above solution is not the key of resolving this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you have tried WebDriverWait, ExplicitWait, and you don't want to use sleep, you can try use below code:

```html
def waitForElement(driver, by, value):
    elements = driver.find_elements(by, value)
    i=0
    while i < 1000 and len(elements)<1:
        sleep(0.01)
        i = i+1
    if i == 1000:
        print "can not find the element in 10 seconds"
        return False
    else:
        print "find element in %d seconds" % i*0.01
        return True
```